# When I remove/replace a line it leaves the line in file? Live visitor counter php

Tags: php

So currently I'm working on a live visitor counter for my website mostly just to add things but I have found a few sources but they don't work, I have rewritten multiple sources and here's my current code.

```php
<?php
function livecount() {
    $dbfiledirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/inc/livecountdb.txt";
$time_out = 140; // 140 seconds until we recognize them as gone.
$getdbinformation = file($dbfiledirectory);



foreach ($getdbinformation as $lines){
    $splittedtime = explode(";",$lines);
    if ($splittedtime[0] + $time_out< date('his', time())){
        $changing = file_get_contents($dbfiledirectory);
        $contents = str_replace($lines, '', $changing);
        file_put_contents($dbfiledirectory, $contents);
    }
}
$contentsdir = file_get_contents($dbfiledirectory);
$pattern = preg_quote(get_client_ip(), '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
if (preg_match($pattern, $contentsdir, $matches)) {
    $changing = file_get_contents($dbfiledirectory);
    $contents = str_replace($matches[0], '', $changing);
    file_put_contents($dbfiledirectory, $contents);
} else {
    $ip = date('his', time()) . ";" . get_client_ip();

    $myFile2 = $dbfiledirectory;
    $myFileLink2 = fopen($myFile2, 'w+') or die("Can't open file.");
    fwrite($myFileLink2, $ip);
    fclose($myFileLink2);
}

echo count (file($dbfiledirectory));
}

function get_client_ip()
{
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if (getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

The problem I'm having is when it removes/replaces the IP;time it still leaves a line in the txt file which causes an error.

Ps - sorry for the sloppy code, I've been on this for hours and its had better days.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp `/^.*$pattern.*\$/m` is setup as "multi line". This means each line is treated as it's own string.

That's fine, but when using the dollar delimiter - it matches **either** the end of the string, or newline character - but doesn't include that in the "body" of the regex.

Looking at the PHP docs (*under "m" flag*):

> ...while the "end of line" metacharacter ($) matches only at the end of the string, or before a terminating newline (unless D modifier is set)...
>
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

So what can you do? You can remove the ($) from the end and instead check for a newline character.

```php
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\n/m";
```

If you have cases where there is no proceeding newline character (e.g possibly last entry) - you could chuck a `?` after the `\n`

```php
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\n?/m";
```

NOTE: your current setup is only replacing a single match - I'm not sure if this is intended or not but thought I would mention